# Does the save method only updates passed field when saving an existing object?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's say I have this object saved in MongoDB:

```
{ "hello" : "goodbye", "_id" : ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65"), "test" : "world" };
```

And I do

```
db.table.save({"_id" : ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65"), "test" : "changed value"});
```

Will it UPDATE the existing record? (test's value will be "changed" and the rest will be intact), Or create a new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you pass the _id and use "save" it will update it.

```
> db.test.insert({ "hello" : "goodbye", "_id" : ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65"), "test" : "world" });
> db.test.save({"_id" : ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65"), "test" : "changed value"});
> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65"), "test" : "changed value" }
```

Sorry, missed the second part of your question. You're looking for this:

```
db.test.update({_id: ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65")}, {$set:{test:"changed value"}});
```

Comment: But if the object has 20 fields, and I pass the _id and only 3 fields. Will it update these 3 fields and leave the rest of the fields intact? Or it will blank them? Thanks

Comment: It will blank them if you do it like you have in your example. However, there is syntax to update only 3 fields without removing the rest. Check out $set at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set